# Is it possible to move container on a particular width?

Tags: magento-2.1.9

How it is possible to change the position of a container in particular width for example:(768 pixel).My task is to change the position of sidebar.main block to the bottom of products listing in  catalog category view page on mobile width.Actually sidebar.main is showing above the product listing in mobile width.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved the element before sidebar additional and now it works perfectly.
just paste the below code in app->design->frontend ->vendor name->custom theme->Magento_Theme->layout->default.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<move element="sidebar.main" destination="sidebar.additional" before="- "/>   
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: This is not an answer ,no code , no how you did it , nothing ..

Comment: Bro you can use the above code and try it out,this helped me to fix my requirement.